# Facebook Graph API Explorer returns OAUTH Exception

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the Graph API Explorer tool I'm using this query:

```
search?q=myemail@gmail.com&type=user
```

But for whatever reasons I'm getting this returned.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

The access token is there. And other requests work, like this one:

```
me?fields=id,name
```

Here's the return value

```
{
  "id": "somelongnumber", 
  "name": "my name"
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, are there additional permissions that I have to setup to get search to work?

---

*Edit*: Here's the screenshot of my user permissions:

[image]

[image]

I have also tried using an application token, but same thing.

---

*More updates:*

Querying for names seem to work just fine:

```
search?q=FirstName LastName&type=user
```

returns valid results, but email returns me oath exception. Did facebook change the way they allow for email searches?

Comment: Some reading https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: @StephaneBruckert Eh.. I'm pretty sure I have a user access token set up. Not sure what in particular I'm supposed to be reading?

Comment: Ok then your access token is not valid because you don't have the right permissions. Either read about [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2) or "facebook permissions", this has also been posted plenty of times on SO.

Comment: @StephaneBruckert just to be safe I checked on every single User permission, so that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @StephaneBruckert edited my question to include a couple of screenshots for the user permissions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Search API with email address not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746530/facebook-search-api-with-email-address-not-working)

Comment: Sorry if I didn't get straight to the point in my comments, I read your thread a bit too quickly. We get these `Must have a valid access_token` problem a bit too often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it was possible, you can't search users by their e-mail addresses anymore. As the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search) states, the `q` value must refer to the name of a user.

> #### Available Search Types
>
> - **Type:** `user`
> - **Description:** search for a person (if they allow their name to be searched for)
> - **`q` value:** name

Also the dot character which is/are present in every e-mail address would also break your Graph request. In the current Graph API syntax, `.` marks the beginning of a subfield, for instance:

```
/me?fields=friends.limit(10)
                  ^
```

How would the email be delimited? As you can see,

`/search?q=john@gmail&type=user` "works"

whereas

`/search?q=john@gmail.com&type=user` doesn't.

---

**Edit:** This feature has been disabled in April 2013 and Facebook reported:

> *This functionality was deprecated because
> of low utilization, and we have no current plans to re-enable it. If
> you have a valid use case for this feature please describe it here for
> consideration.* Marie Hagman — Facebook Team

*Source: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/453298034751100/*

Comment: Some searching around the net seem to indicate that email is/was supported at some point. Was it removed completely? Not to mention that you can search through the facebook search as well...

Comment: Look at my edit. Also know that not all features have to exist in the API. It's like "can you see a list of all your friends on Facebook?" yes! "can you see a list of all your friends on the Graph API explorer? [no](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484893/fetch-facebook-friends-list-of-logged-user/27484960)!